# decrypt/encrypt large data using RSA public key

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, rsa

I wan encrypt large DATA using an RSA public key then decrypt it using the private key 
So my encryption function is :

```
unsigned char* encryptFile::rsaEncrypt( RSA *pubKey, const unsigned char* msg, int msg_len, int *enc_len )
{
    int rsa_size = RSA_size(pubKey);
    int block_size = rsa_size - 12;
    int blocks = msg_len/block_size;
    int rest = msg_len % block_size;
    unsigned char* enc = 0;
    int curr_len = 0;
    int i = 0;
    if (0 == rest) {
        enc = (unsigned char*)malloc(blocks*rsa_size + 1);
    }
    else {
        enc = (unsigned char*)malloc((blocks+1)*rsa_size + 1);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < blocks; i++) {
        if (0 > (curr_len = RSA_public_encrypt(block_size , msg + i*block_size, enc + i*rsa_size, pubKey, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING))) {
            printf("ERROR: RSA_public_encrypt: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
        }
        *enc_len += curr_len;
    }
        if (0 != rest) {
            if (0 > (curr_len = RSA_public_encrypt(rest , msg + i*block_size, enc + i*rsa_size, pubKey, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING))) {
            printf("ERROR: RSA_public_encrypt: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
        }
        *enc_len += curr_len;
    }
    if( *enc_len == -1 )
        printf("ERROR: RSA_public_encrypt: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
        cout << *enc_len << endl;
    return enc;
}
```

And it's working fine !
Now when i want decrypt it i'm using this code

```
int rsa_size = RSA_size(privKey);
int msg_len = encBinLen;
int block_size = rsa_size;
int blocks = msg_len/block_size;
int rest = msg_len % block_size;
unsigned char* enc = 0;
int curr_len = 0;
enc_len = 0;
int i = 0;
if (0 == rest) {
    enc = (unsigned char*)malloc(blocks*rsa_size + 1);
}
else {
    enc = (unsigned char*)malloc((blocks+1)*rsa_size + 1);
}
for (i = 0; i < blocks; i++) {
    if (0 > (curr_len = RSA_private_decrypt(block_size , msg + i*block_size, enc + i*rsa_size, privKey, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING))) {
        printf("ERROR: RSA_public_encrypt: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
    }
    enc_len += curr_len;
}
    if (0 != rest) {
        if (0 > (curr_len = RSA_private_decrypt(rest , msg + i*block_size, enc + i*rsa_size, privKey, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING))) {
        printf("ERROR: RSA_public_encrypt: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
    }
    enc_len += curr_len;
}
if( enc_len == -1 )
    printf("ERROR: RSA_public_encrypt: %s\n", ERR_error_string(ERR_get_error(), NULL));
cout << enc;
```

Anyway when i run that some of the data got decrypted but i still see some weird chars as in seen [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3jUt.png)
So i just want understand what i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: What did you expect to get if you think those are "weird chars"?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I'm decrypting so i should get normal text .. the text that have been encrypted !!

Comment: RSA is not a block cipher and should never be used in this way. It is very tricky to get right and it won't be secure. You should either do [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) or [RSA-KEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_encapsulation) in conjunction with AES.

Comment: @ArtjomB. what about using Crypto++ ?

Comment: RSA is not designed to encrypt large data, the encryption length is limited to less than the key size and it is not fast. Generally data is encrypted with a symmetric cipher such as AES and if an asymmetric key is necessary the symmetric key is encrypted by asymmetric encryption. This is sometimes called hybrid encryption and is similar to what HTTPS/TLS does. Encryption large data with multiple RSA encryptions just does not make sense.

Comment: Whether you use OpenSSL or Crypto++ doesn't make a difference. You need some higher-level library like GPG.

Comment: @ArtjomB. thanks .. i'm going to use hybrid encryption .. i answered my own question !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**The solution is to use [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) !**
Thnks to Artjom B. & zaph

Comment: For my personal survey, why did you choose RSA for encryption?

Comment: I thought it's secure enough !

Comment: OK. Wondering why public/private key encryption as opposed to symmetric key encryption. in other words are two separate keys needed to meet the needs?

Comment: *[Adaptive chosen ciphertext attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability)* discussed in the wiki page is known as IND-CCA2. You can use [Discrete Logarithm Integrated Encryption Scheme](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Discrete_Logarithm_Integrated_Encryption_Scheme) or [Elliptic Curve Integrated Encryption Scheme](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Elliptic_curve_integrated_encryption_scheme) to achieve it. I seem to recall code OpenSSL-based code for ECIES. You will have to search the web, though. The project does not support it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use `enc_len` instead of `i*rsa_size` as shifter for output in `RSA_private_decrypt(block_size , msg + i*block_size, enc + i*rsa_size, privKey, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING)` call.